# Is java.util.logging.Logger.log() is an chain of responsibility pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is java.util.logging.Logger.log()  is a chain of responsibility pattern?If so how log method call is getting chained for the next call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the relevant [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/logging/Logger.java#Logger.log%28java.util.logging.LogRecord%29):

```
// Post the LogRecord to all our Handlers, and then to
// our parents' handlers, all the way up the tree.

Logger logger = this;
while (logger != null) {
    Handler targets[] = logger.getHandlers();

    //...

    if (!logger.getUseParentHandlers()) {
      break;
    }

    logger = logger.getParent();
}
}
```

As you can see each logging record is passed to every `Handler` assigned to a given logger and, if `useParentHandlers` is `true`, the same algorithm is applied to parent all the way up to the top.

So essentially this is a chain of responsibility pattern where each element in the chain might handle piece of the request.

Comment: Yes, I already provided [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/logging/Logger.java#Logger.log(java.util.logging.LogRecord)) link (see `log(LogRecord)` method), it looks the same in Sun JDK.